# Running react-scripts app with input from another server

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, react-scripts

I'm having some difficulty passing information between different servers and them showing what I want. I have one server where I get my data from (a JSON file), and another server which runs a react application. I want to pass information to this react application (preferably the json content), and then serve the react application, maybe from an express app's post method?

Is there a way to pass information in this way? Right now I'm trying to fetch the data from one server, the webpacked index.html from another, and mashing them together with some string parsing (using window.data global values to get the json file in there). This doesn't include icons, and I get errors about disconnecting from the development server when I run.

To reiterate, I want to serve a react application with input coming from a completely different server. If you have any tips for how to accomplish this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is it not possible for you to 'fetch(...)' that JSON from within your react app ?

Comment: @DimaGershman Management decision... I could probably convince them to accept this, but I'd still need to pass in a url for the fetch. Would this be easier than passing in an entire json? The react app can be used in a lot of different modes, depending on the json input, and it's supposed to be "includable" outside of other react apps (which means static html file).

Comment: Do you mean to embed the whole app in another app, or embedding components? If that within static html file, then maybe you could use URL parameter , which your react app would use for 'fetch()'

Comment: @DimaGershman Embed the app in another app.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (pseudo code):

```
YourReactComponent {

  componentDidUpdate() {
        fetch(other_server_URL, ...)
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            }
        })
        .then((jsonString) => { 
            this.parseYourJson(jsonString);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem with this is that I don't know the URL. But I just thought about being able to pass it as a query param. Weird how you can forget the simplest things.

Comment: Yep. query params would work. ( Don't forget to "URL encode" it :))